# Exception raised when using a Linq query with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listbox

*I removed a substantial amount of text from this question because I feel it needed to be more succinct. - Serg*

Here's what I'm trying to do. User selects a State, then a ComboBox loads with Cities in that State, then when user selects a Сity a ListBox loads all projects from that City.

When running the method that's supposed to load the projects to the ComboBox, I receive this error:

> Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. Inner
>   Exception is: "{"Specified cast is not
>   valid."}"valid."}"

This is the method that causes the exception:

```
private void LoadProjectsToListBox(long idCity)
{
    ProjectRepository projectRepo = new ProjectRepository();    

    //This line causes the error.
    var projects = projectRepo.FindAllProjects().Where(c => c.IDCity == 1).ToList();
}
```

In the Linq query, you'll see that I'm comparing against a hard coded number. 1, is a valid ID of a City that has Projects so it should work. The exception is only raised when I give the Linq query a City ID that has Projects. So it seems the error is raised when the query returns results.

Here is the SQL statements I used to generate the Project and City tables:

```
create table City
(
    ID integer primary key autoincrement,
    Name string,
    IDState integer references State(ID)
);

create table Project
(
    ID integer primary key autoincrement,
    Name string,
    StartDate text,
    IDManager integer references Manager(ID),
    IDCity integer references City(ID),
    IDDepartment integer references Department(ID),
    ContactNumber string,
    Description string
);
```

What strikes me as odd is that using the **exact same pattern and access code** to show a list of Departments (just another table in my database) everything works as expected. For example here's how I load Departments right now just for testing:

```
private void LoadProjectsToListBox(long idCity)
{
    ProjectRepository projectRepo = new ProjectRepository();
    DepartmentRepository departmentRepo = new DepartmentRepository();

    //Doesn't work - raises exception.
    var projects = projectRepo.FindAllProjects().Where(c => c.IDCity == 1).ToList();

    //Works exactly as expected.
    var deps = departmentRepo.FindAllDepartments().Where(c => c.IDParentDepartment == 7).ToList();

    lstProjects.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in deps)
    {
        lstProjects.Items.Add(item.Name);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The FindAllDepartments(), FindAllCities(), FindAllProjects() methods are essentially the same.

```
DocumentsDBEntities db = new DocumentsDBEntities();

public IQueryable<Project> FindAllProjects()
{
    return db.Projects;
}

public IQueryable<City> FindAllCities()
{
    return db.Cities;
}

public IQueryable<Department> FindAllDepartments()
{
    return db.Departments;
}
```

As mentioned before, Department fetching works; Project fetching causes the exception.

**Edit 3:**

I fixed it! The problem was with using the datatype of 'Text' in the Project table. If I changed the datatype from that column from 'Text' to 'String' it works flawlessly. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace.  You mentioned the inner exception, can you provide the stack trace for that?

Comment: In the part that works you add just a string (project.Name)? In the one that doesn't work (if I can understand the question correctly), it appears the data-source is wired up to a list of objects and the error sounds like it is failing in retrieving suitable values for said objects. I believe the observed behavior may be a red-herring. Happy coding.

Comment: If I just use this line I still have the error fire:             var x = projectRepo.FindAllProjects().Where(l => l.IDCity == idCity).ToList();

Comment: have you changed anything in the database? what's the passed value of idCity ?

Comment: Like I said, if even I ignore the passed value and just use a hand typed number the error is risen when the number represents an ID for a City that has Projects. If I give it a number to a City with no project no error is risen.

Comment: Where's the method `FindAllProjects()`?  That's probably where the invalid cast exception is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem last week!  In my case the problem was that some of the tables I had pulled over to the .dbml file had a different database connection (test vs production) and even though the tables were (conceptually) the same, it was impossible to cast a table of type 'db1.table1' to 'db2.table1'.  I don't know if that is the root of your problem or not, but I hope this helps in some way.  Making sure that all my tables were coming from the exact same database connection was what solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), Text datatype doesn't allow comparison with == (or OrderBy, for that matter). Unless I misunderstood the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You most start your query with city (up to down):

```
var projects = projectRepo.FindAllCities()
    .Where(c => c.ID == 1)
    .Select(p => p.Projects)
    .ToList();
```